# /usr/bin/env: 'node\r': No such file or directory

Tags: docker, npm, command-line

I'm having this issue when running the following command:

```
docker-compose run npm run dev
```

I'm in cmd terminal in win10 and I think the error is related to CRLF/LF end of lines.

The following is the whole error :

> ```
> > @ dev /var/www
> > npm run development
>
> > @ development /var/www
> > cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js
>
> /usr/bin/env: 'node\r': No such file or directory
> npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
> npm ERR! syscall spawn
> npm ERR! file sh
> npm ERR! errno ENOENT
> npm ERR! @ development: `cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js`
> npm ERR! spawn ENOENT
> npm ERR!
> npm ERR! Failed at the @ development script.
> npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
>
> npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
> npm ERR!     /root/.npm/_logs/2020-06-19T13_04_14_658Z-debug.log
> npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
> npm ERR! errno 1
> npm ERR! @ dev: `npm run development`
> npm ERR! Exit status 1
> npm ERR!
> npm ERR! Failed at the @ dev script.
> npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
>
> npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
> npm ERR!     /root/.npm/_logs/2020-06-19T13_04_14_679Z-debug.log
> ```

Answer (score 4):

The `\r` in `node\r` is probably the key: you saved some file using Windows line endings (CRLF) whereas Linux expect LF line endings.

As I'm not accustomed with NodeJs, I can't really tell you which file use wrong line ending here.

Comment: yes that's what i think also, however i tried modifing the concerned files to LF but i'm still getting the same error, thank you anyways :)